# Photoshop 3d video export is not showing lighting

Tags: adobe-photoshop, video

I have created a 3d object in Photoshop which I have animated in a simple, 2-second sequence. [Figure 1.1] I want to export this as a video with transparency/alpha. However, when I try to run the exported render, all that plays is a black screen.

This baffled me a little bit and, while tweaking settings around, I ended up exporting the sequence as PNG keyframes. Once I saw the keyframes, I realized that it is exporting the object properly, but completely without lighting [Figure 1.2].

**How do I properly export my 3d object as a video with transparency and lighting included?**

Figure 1.1: A screenshot of my workspace
[image: Figure 1.1: A screenshot of my workspace]

Figure 1.2: One of several exported PNG keyframes
[image: Figure 1.2: One of several exported PNG keyframes]

*Troubleshooting Update*:

- I tried closing and re-opening photoshop. No luck.
- I've tried exporting as JPEGs in case the transparency was causing issues. No luck there either.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that updating to Photoshop CC 2014 fixed this problem. All lighting, meshes, and materials is now visible in exports.